# Brower's autofill is not working in ember.js forms

Tags: ember.js, autofill

It's not uncommon user needs to login. And in most browsers, there is a password manager. The problem is that for forms, that are built using javascript, browser doesn't recognize forms. And autofill feature doesn't work. Any work around?

Ex:

`<form>
  {{input value=name name="firstname"}}
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `autocomplete="true"` should do it.

So like this: `{{input value=name name="email" autocomplete="true"}}`

UPDATE::  I'm not sure why your form is not working, I would check all options such as that auto-fill is enabled in your browser, but for myself, the following form in the jsbin allows me to autofill when I click on the first box.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jifuxako/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for replying...The default will be `true` for `autocompelete`, even adding explicitly `autocomplete=true` its not working... :(

Comment: I think the value of `autocomplete` should be either `on` or `off` according to the HTML5 specification (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).